# Make custom radio button css

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to make custom radio button that will look like this

[image]

The problem I have is with alignment, you will see that name of option is moving in new line. but radio button stays on first?

This is what I have for now

**HTML**

```
  <div> <input id="option-one" name="radio" value="one" checked="checked" type="radio"> <label
                for="option-one"> <span></span> First Option </label> </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.radio {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto;
  grid-gap: .5em;
  font-size: 2.25rem;
  color: red;

}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"] + label {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
}

input[type="radio"] + label span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin: -2px 10px 0 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
}

input[type="radio"] + label span {
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 700;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label span {
  background-color: #ff8800;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

input[type="radio"] + label span,
input[type="radio"]:checked + label span {
  -webkit-transition: background-color .24s linear;
  -o-transition: background-color .24s linear;
  -moz-transition: background-color .24s linear;
  transition: background-color .24s linear;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap around the input and the label inside a div and have flex styles for it :

```
 <div class="container">
        <div>
          <input
            id="option-one"
            name="radio"
            value="one"
            checked="checked"
            type="radio"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="option-one">
            <span></span> First Option
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
```

CSS

```
    .container {
        display : flex ;
        align-items : center ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below snippet with help of css **dispaly: flex;** property.

```css
.radio-area {
    font-family: Arial;
    display: inline-flex;
    font-size: 1.75rem;
    color: blue;
    padding-left: 34px;
    position: relative;
}
.radio-area input{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
.radio-area div{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 240px; 
}
.radio-area div::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: 0;
    top: 2px;
    transition: background-color .24s linear;
}
.radio-area input:checked ~ div::before {
    background-color: #ff8800;
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
```

```html
<label class="radio-area">
    <input name="radio" value="one" checked="checked" type="radio">
    <div>U.N.O-Laan 100 2620 Hemiksem</div>
</label>
<br>
<br>
<label class="radio-area">
    <input name="radio" value="two" type="radio">
    <div>U.N.O-Laan 200 2620 Hemiksem</div>
</label>
```

Comment: Adding <br> is not possible, because this one line i dont where to break, css shoudl break it

Comment: @MiomirDancevic Okay, so you can easily remove <br> tag and you can define width of text element as you want. Let me edit to remove <br> tag.

Comment: Ok, can you make proper answer

Comment: @MiomirDancevic Now run the snippet, I just added **width** on **.radio-area div** element after meet word length then *line will be break*.